# Operators: "bool++" in C#

Tags: c#, razor, boolean, unary-operator

Having

```
public void Main()
{
  int i = 0; 
  Console.WriteLine($"I was {i++}, now I is {i}");
  bool b = true;
  Console.WriteLine($"B was {b}, now B is {b}");
}
//I was 0, now I is 1
//B was True, now B is True
```

Is there a possibility to change the `B` value "inline"?

Practical need: In inline Razor

```
bool isActive = true;
@foreach(var item in list) {
    <li class="@(isActive-- ? "active": "")">...
}
```

to produce

```
<li class="active">...
<li class="">...
<li class="">...
<li class="">...
<li class="">...
```

Workaround for the practical example with `integers`:

```
int isActive = 1;
@foreach(var item in list) {
    <li class="@(isActive-- > 0 ? "active": "")">...
}
```

Comment: You mean like negation operator or? You can always have `if(b = DoSomething()))`

Comment: rather like negation operator

Comment: What do you mean by "change it" inline?

Comment: In your case you are looking for the decrement before, i.e. `--isActive` rather than after.

Comment: @Amy, see the practical example, do the "mybool = !myBool" with "myBool--"

Comment: You shouldn't be performing computations like this in the view; compute the value before you bind this data to the view.

Comment: @Servy make an abstraction about the view usage. is rather a c# language question.. )

Answer (score 1):

You can apply assignment operator inline. It returns assigned value:

```
// b = !b both assigns false to b and returns assigned value
Console.WriteLine($"B was {b}, now B is {b = !b}");
// B was True, now B is False
```

For your razor view example you can (ab)use it like this:

```
bool active = true;
Console.WriteLine($"B is {(active ? (active = false) ? "" :"active" : "")}");
Console.WriteLine($"B is {(active ? (active = false) ? "" : "active" : "")}");
Console.WriteLine($"B is {(active ? (active = false) ? "" : "active" : "")}");
// outputs B is active
// B is
// B is
```

Not that I recommend this, but as you said it's just a language question.

Comment: how to do it working in my Razor sample? @(isActive? changeIt)

Comment: I found a solution (in updated OP) with Integers... but with bools is more complicated :)

Answer (score 0):

`inlining` in the sense of changing a variable in the `if-conditition` is possible.

```
var b = false;
if((b = !b) == true) {
    Console.WriteLine("Hi");
}
```

This compiles an will print `Hi`.

The same goes for your razor statement, or while formatting a string:

```
Console.WriteLine($"b was {b}, now b is {b = !b}");
// b was true, now b is false
```

Regarding your example,  this is not possible with one `ternary if` statement.

We can use one statement to set the variable to false and to **not** print *active*.

```
b ? (b = false) : "";
```

We can then nest another `if` statement to print the *active*. Because `b` is already `false` we need to negate b. The empty string in the `else`-path will never be reached but is needed to satisfy the compiler.

```
!(b = false) ? "active" : "never reached"
```

After combining those we get:

```
b ? (!(b = false) ? "active" : "") : "";
```

This will only emit `active` for the first item.

```
var b = true;
Console.WriteLine(b ? (!(b = false) ? "active" : "") : ""); // prints "active"
Console.WriteLine(b ? (!(b = false) ? "active" : "") : ""); // prints ""
Console.WriteLine(b ? (!(b = false) ? "active" : "") : ""); // prints ""
```

Comment: thanks, please propose a solution for Razor in the updated OP example

Comment: @Serge does this help?

Comment: I also had this idea, finally abandoned, because was unreadable... put that in the code only me will understand what does it mean... the @evk example more readable... bit finally I used the Integer solution... i didn't find a good solution for my thing...

Comment: @Serge I wouldn't advise using this solution either. In fact, I wouldn't use the integer solution as well. Having a ternary solution with side effects doesn't help the readability and testability. I would push this logic into the model, making it more expressive.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the @() expression syntax:

```
<li class="@(isActive ? "active" : " ")">My link here</li>
```

Comment: I need just the first active class, not the other ones

Comment: I need isActive to change from true to false just one time.